# Getting number of rows and data of that row in a single query using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a log-in system where initially I am checking whether the username/password combination is correct and then fetching the columns to set session variables

Here  is my code

```
$sql='select uid,name from users where username=? and password=?';
$query=$con->prepare($sql);
$result=$query->execute(array($username,$password));
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//check if a single row is returned 

if(($query->fetchColumn())===1)
    {
        //set session variables
        header('Location: lading_page.php');
    }
else echo "Invalid username/password";
```

**1)** `fetchColumn()` is giving wrong result as **3** (though I have single row matching that parameters and 15 coulmns per row) whereas if the `$sql` had been

`$sql='select count(*) from users where username=? and password=?';`

gives correct answer as **1** Why?

**2)** I saw the php manual and I found that `rowCount()` is gauranteed only for DML queries and it suggests [workaround for SELECT](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) but it costs 2 queries per login.

Is there a way I can do using single query?

**EDIT**

Now I am using something like this and it seems to work fine but few problems .see comments

```
$sql='select uid,name from users where username=? and password=?';
$query=$con->prepare($sql);
$result=$query->execute(array($username,$password));

$rows= $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(count($rows)===1)
    {
          //I reached here
        echo $_SESSION['id']=$rows['uid']; //undefined index uid
        echo $_SESSION['name']=$rows['name'];//undefined index name
        //header('Location: landing_page.php');
    }
else $error="Invalid username/password";
```

Comment: As per your edit: Is `session_start();` used inside all your pages and are the session names/variables assigned?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Yes .But I am getting **Undefined Index**

Comment: Then do a `var_dump();` on `$_SESSION` and `$_SESSION['id']` and `$_SESSION['name']` see what shows up. If nothing shows up, then they're not properly assigned, or not in the right place.

Comment: @Fred-ii-:As I said I am getting **undeined index uid** when i `execute $rows['uid']`.The `var_dump()` shows it as null .The problem is in accessing the column values in `$rows['uid']` .Please help

Comment: Instead of having 3 `===` in `if(count($rows)===1)` can you try `if(count($rows)==1)` or `if(count($rows) >0)`

Comment: @Fred-ii-:Same problem.I am reaching inside the `if` block.The only problem is `$rows['uid']` is returning null.

Comment: I think I know what "could" be the problem. Instead of an `if` condition, try using a `while`. I.e.: `while(count($rows)===1)` or `while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))` or something like that. Not sure how it's done with PDO.

Comment: `while(count($rows)===1) ` is an infinite loop

Comment: Are you sure you have a column called `uid` and not `id`? I don't want to set up a whole DB to test this. You have data in there, right?

Comment: @Fred-ii-:Yes I have a column `uid` and there are currently 5 rows in that table with 1 table matching the parameters that I am passing as `username` and `password`

Comment: @Fred-ii-:Soved the problem it was `$rows[0]['uid']` and not `$rows['uid']`

Comment: @Fred-ii-:Sir,I didn't notice that.I apologise it was my fault.

Comment: No problemo. No (permanent) damage done ;-) Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope i got you right on this.

try it with Fetch all

```
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

in your case

```
$sql='select uid,name from users where username=? and password=?';
$query=$con->prepare($sql);
$result=$query->execute(array($username,$password));


// check if a single row is returned
// i guess to avoid the warnings you can just set the array befor like
// $row = array();
// or put @ befor the VARS in the TRUE statement

$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

/** 
if you have more than one result you can look at them like this

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    echo $row['uid'];
}
**/

if((count($rows)===1)
    {
        echo $_SESSION['id']=@$rows['uid']; 
        echo $_SESSION['name']=@$rows['name'];
        // header('Location: lading_page.php');
    }
else echo "Invalid username/password";
```

Comment: Now how will I access the column values of that returned row.Do I need to execute another query?Assume the columns as `uid` and `name`.Please update that.

Comment: :`echo $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` This returns an array not a number.Am I supposed to use count() also?

Comment: Please see the EDIT.near to completion

Comment: of corse you do :) btw these are no errors, these are warnings. because the war is never set before. just add a @ befor the var, see my edits

Answer (score 0):

fetchColumn() - Returns a single **column** from the next row of a result set. It's not a number of resulting rows like in "select count(*) ...", it's the value of (in your case) first column (uid) in a result row.